# Condition to have the Fourier transform invertability

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

If $g(t)$ is an absolutely integrable function on $\mathbb{R}$ (so in $L^1$) we have:

$$\mathcal{F^{-1}} \circ \mathcal{F} (g) =g$$

but this can also be true for a function having asymptotic expansion like:

$$ g(t)= K t^{-a} \; \; \; t \to \infty$$ with $0<\Re (a)<1$

(this type of function is not in $L^{1}$) What are the minimum condition to have $\mathcal{F^{-1}} \circ \mathcal{F} (g) =g$ (keeping $g$ and $\mathcal{F} (g) $ as functions, so without use of distribution)

Any reference on this subject ?

Comment: What do you mean precisely by $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ here? Is it the inverse Fourier transform? Or do you simply mean that $\mathcal{F}$ is injective? Do you want the equality almost everywhere or do you consider them as operators on some spaces? There are a lot of different results and they depend on the precise definitions.

Comment: $\mathcal{F^{-1}}$ is the inverse Fourier transform, and I would like to know when the inversion formula can be used so that the double integral given by   $\mathcal{F^{-1}} \circ \mathcal{F} $ is equal to the initial function on $\mathbb{R}^*$ (need to remove zero as -due to asymptotic I fixed for $g(t)$- the Fourier transform of $g$ will have a singularity in zero but on all other points I would like to have equality)